# Parent process missing child's ready signal

Tags: c#, process

This is how my code looks like at the moment

Parent:

```
myProcess.Start();     
myEventWaitHandle.WaitOne(); 
//do stuff with child process
```

Child:

```
//get ready 
myEventWaitHandle.Set();
```

How can I make sure the parent executes WaitOne() before childrens signal?

Comment: Please edit the post and write what have you already tried.

Comment: You should add more context. I suppose `myProcess` is of type `System.Diagnostics.Process`? A minimal, complete and verifiable example ([jon skeek](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) (say a test case) would help.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing you can do to ensure this.  Nor is it ever important, a WaitOne() that completes instantly is a happy one.  There is no problem to be solved here.